# jquery and css: page content loading animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

so many web site show little animation when content load in background. linked in is one of the site they show a nice animation when content load. here i am pasting a screen shot and just see and tell me how could i show this kind of animation when page content loads.

[image]

please share the idea to develop my page as a result i could show this kind of animation when i will call my server side function to load data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "easy" to achive. Let's put an example:

1. In your index you code something similar to the image you attached
2. Then, you load all the website content using ajax
3. Once the content is retrieved from your server, you replace the dummy HTML with the real data.

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle link what you said.

Comment: A better option is that you create a jsfiddle where you try to achieve your idea, then you post it here, and we will try to help you.